# Fundamental theorem of algebra in different functional form

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Consider the polynomial function: $f(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2 x^2+\cdots+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$, with $x$ and $c_0,c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_{n-1}$ are complex numbers. $|f(x)|$ is continuous and there exists closed and compact disc $Q:=\{ x: |x|\le P_0\}$, with $\inf_{x\in Q} |f(x)|$ exists at some $x_0$ in the interior of $Q$. Each circle $x_0+we^{i\theta}$ of radius $w$ centered at $x_0$ lies interior of $Q$ for all small $w>0$, $0\le\theta <2\pi$. Let the new polynomial be $h(v):=f(x_0+v)=b_0+b_1v+b_2 v^2+\cdots+b_{n-1}v^{n-1}+v^n$, where $v:=we^{i\theta}$, with $b_0=f(x_0)$ and other coefficients in the form of $c_0...c_{n-1},x_0$. Let $b_t \neq0,t\ge1$ be the first coefficient not equal to zero (since it may occur that $b_1=0$). Show that we have $|b_{t+1}v^{t+1}+b_{t+2}v^{t+2}+\cdots+ b_{n-1}v^{n-1}+v^n|<|b_t||v|^t$ if we pick $w=|v|$ small enough. Provide the magnitude of $w$.

I used the Euler's formula of $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ and the fact that $e^{i(\theta+\gamma)}=e^{i\theta}e^{i\gamma}$ and plug in $v:=we^{i\theta}$ to rewrite the inequality as: $|(b_{t+1}w^{t+1}e^{i\theta}+b_{t+2}w^{t+2}e^{2i\theta}+\cdots+b_{n-1}w^{n-1}e^{(n-j-1) i\theta}+w^ne^{(n-j)i\theta})||e^{i\theta t}|<|b_t||w^te^{i\theta t}|$ but don't know what to do next or if the steps are wrong.

Comment: Or if the problem can be simplified to find the  $w$ that satisfies $|(b_{t+1}w^{t+1}e^{i\theta}+b_{t+2}w^{t+2}e^{2i\theta}+...+b_{n-1}w^{n-1}e^{(n-j-1)i\theta}+w^ne^{(n-j)i\theta})|<|b_t||w^t|$

Comment: Divide by $|v|^t$. This is the proof of D'Alembert/Argant, cut-the-knot and wikipedia have summaries of the steps.